# Un navire « armé en opération par 1900 marins » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, syntaxe, formulation

Dans un texte de présentation d'une [vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIzVgY-r70c) sur le porte-avions [Charles de Gaulle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle_(porte-avions)) je lis ce qui suit :

> [...] Préparez-vous à découvrir les coulisses du plus imposant navire
>   de guerre français, **armé en opération par** 1900 marins !

*[Armer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/armer) un navire* c'est [le] « pourvoir du personnel, du matériel et des approvisionnements nécessaires à la navigation que doit effectuer ce navire » ; *armer en guerre* c'est « pourvoir un bateau de tout ce qui lui est nécessaire pour faire la guerre » (TLFi). Par ailleurs normalement l'[*opération*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/op%C3%A9ration) c'est l'« ensemble de mouvements stratégiques ou de manœuvres tactiques d'une armée en campagne, exécutés en vue d'atteindre un objectif donné » (TLFi) et on y trouve associé le syntagme *être en opération*, ce qui diffère du calque sémantique pour [*être en service*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3654).

- Peut-on expliquer la syntaxe de la phrase, comment s'imbrique *en
  opération* avec le verbe ici (est-ce comme *armer en guerre*... *pour
  faire une opération* ?) ?
- Pourquoi trouve-t-on la [préposition](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2126) *par* plutôt que *de*
  (*pourvoir qqc. de qqc., armé de, opéré par*) : les marins sont-ils l'agent qui effectue l'action ou le résultat de cette action ?

Comment: Au risque d'étaler ma potentielle ignorance, je dirais que la phrase est légèrement bancale, et que vous avez raison d'être surpris. A voir ce qu'en pensent les autres francophones...

Comment: Aidez-moi, svp, car je suis un peu slow cette aprèm et je n'arrive pas à trouver le texte de présentation duquel vous avez lu la phrase en question. Une phrase similaire se trouve à 1:15 de la video elle-meme (et son sous-titre correspondant), mais elle est sans l' "en opération" en question. Merci!

Comment: @PapaPoule Ce n'est pas dans la vidéo, c'est le texte _sous_ la vidéo !

Comment: Tiens, le voila! Merci!

Answer (score 4):

Selon moi vous avez la réponse dans votre question :

> armer en guerre c'est « pourvoir un bateau de tout ce qui lui est nécessaire pour faire la guerre » (TLFi).
>
> Armer un navire c'est [le] « pourvoir du personnel, du matériel et des approvisionnements nécessaires à la navigation que doit effectuer ce navire »

Donc je dirais simplement que "armer en opération" c'est :

> pourvoir un bateau de tout ce qui lui est nécessaire pour partir en opération

Et donc la phrase "Préparez-vous à découvrir les coulisses du plus imposant navire de guerre français, armé en opération par 1900 marins !" pourrait s'écrire avec un vocabulaire moins spécifique :

> Préparez-vous à découvrir les coulisses du plus imposant navire de guerre français, qui peut emmener en opération 1900 marins !

Comment: J'ai offert ma perception de la chose en une autre réponse, mais ne suis pas militaire et ne saurait dire si votre perception est plus ou moins éclairée que la mienne. Si vous en connaissez davantage sur l’art militaire, n'hésitez pas à me le faire savoir et je retirerai ma réponse, si elle s’avérait exposer une information fausse.

Answer (score 3):

> Le navire est *armé **et** en opération*.

Il est *préparé **et** en action*, qui peut être exercice, surveillance, sur zone comme *en* guerre

---

***Complément***

> (navire…) *armé en opération **par 1900 marins***.

se lit :

> (navire…), *armé en opération* (et l’opération [en cours] est réalisée) *par 1900 marins*.

La phrase est correct pour tout marin de « La Royale » héritier des trois mâts cap-horniers : le parler est bref dans la tourmente, on ne fait pas de phrase durant les manœuvres périlleuses.

Tous les hauts gradés sont passé par le trois mâts école *[La Belle Poule](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belle_Poule_(1932))* et sont porteurs d’une tradition qui remontent aux temps des Grecs de l’Antiquité pour qui il y a trois sortes d’hommes : « Les vivants, les morts et ceux qui vont sur la mer ».

Bien sûr aller sur mer de nos jours est moins risqué, mais les fortunes de mer sont toujours possibles, ainsi l’esprit des marins de la Marine Royale de Louis XIV perdure.

La phrase est donc correcte en elle-même :

> *on arme (un navire) **en***…
>
> *l’opération (est exécutée) **par***

mais ce langage corporatiste est tombé en désuétude pour le commun des francophones.

Comment: _...le parler est bref dans la tourmente_, vraiment excellent.